# Value pointed to by a pointer changes after first dereference

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to initialize the integer pointer "p" inside the "init_pointer" function. After the function returns I am printing the pointer and the dereferenced value twice. The first dereference prints the expected value 100, but the second dereference prints random values.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    void init_pointer(int d, int **c){
            (*c) = &d;
    }

    int main(){
            int x = 100;
            int *p;

            init_pointer(x,&p);

            printf("pointer = %p, value = %d\n",p,*p);
            printf("pointer = %p, value = %d\n",p,*p);

            return 0;
    }
```

**Output**:

```
pointer = 0x7fffb4d4b9ac, value = 100
pointer = 0x7fffb4d4b9ac, value = 32567
```

Answer (score 9):

The function has copied the value to a new local variable in `init_pointer(int d, int **c)`

`d` is local to `init_pointer` which was passed by `main` from `x`. Both `x` and `d` are separate variables whose addresses are different. Accessing the address of `d` outside `init_pointer` will lead to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It would not make sense to call the function like this but this will work:

```
void init_pointer(int *d, int **c)
{
        (*c) = d;
}

int main()
{
        int x = 100;
        int *p;

        init_pointer(&x,&p);

        printf("pointer = %p, value = %d\n",p,*p);
        printf("pointer = %p, value = %d\n",p,*p);

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pointer = 0xbfde132c, value = 100
pointer = 0xbfde132c, value = 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void init_pointer(int d, int **c){
        (*c) = &d;
}
```

Here `*c` points to a *local copy* inside `init_pointer()`. Once `init_pointer()` returns, the address becomes invalid, and `p` in `main()` points to a freed address.

Answer (score 0):

In init_pointer you assign the address of the parameter d to *c. The address of the parameter is a stack address.

In the first call to printf, the stack (although deallocated) is still intact, so p points to the discarded parameter d on the stack, which still has a value of 100, and *p is pushed first onto the stack.

In the second call to printf, the first call has overwritten the stack. Although the pointer still points to the same address, its value there has been overwritten by the push of p. Hence p (an address) is printed.

Notes: with "the stack (although deallocated)" I mean the stack of and below sp (intel; growing downward). Also, the stack can have been overwritten at any time, e.g. when interrupts occur.